# How do I create a compound dtype numpy array from existing individual vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, dtype

I am learning about `dtypes` in numpy and I have the following doubt.

I can define a compound type as follows:

```
myrecord = np.dtype([
    ('col1', 'u4'),
    ('col2', 'f8')
])
```

If I have two individual numpy arrays:

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
b=np.array([10.1,20.1,30.1,40.1])
```

How would I generate a third array `c` of type `my_record`?

This is what I tried, which it does not work but it might give an idea on what I am looking for:

```
c=np.array((a,b), dtype=myrecord)
```

This would be the expected output:

```
array([(1, 10.1),
       (2, 20.1),
       (3, 30.1),
       (4, 40.1),],
      dtype=[('col1', '<u4'),('col2', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! You have to zip the `a` and `b` columns together when creating `c`:

```
import numpy as np

myrecord = np.dtype([
    ('col1', 'u4'),
    ('col2', 'f8')
])

a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
b=np.array([10.1,20.1,30.1,40.1])

c = np.array(list(zip(a, b)), dtype=myrecord)
```

Then when we view `c`, you get the desired result:

```
>>>c
array([(1, 10.1), (2, 20.1), (3, 30.1), (4, 40.1)],
      dtype=[('col1', '<u4'), ('col2', '<f8')])
```

Your example code is trying to create a tuple of arrays. What you really wanted is an array of tuples.